# Amazon API Gateway Hourly rate limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am developing an API through Amazon Gateway API. From the docs I can see that it is possible rate limit per second, however there is no mention of the ability to limit per hour - basically I want to limit one of my resources to 1000 requests per hour. Is it OK just to put 0.277 here?

Comment: You're talking 1000 requests per hour across all clients -- not per client -- right?

Comment: correct. I'd like to to be rate limited on a user basis.

Answer (score 2):

API Gateway cannot currently rate limit effectively on a per hour basis.

The API Gateway throttling implementation currently purges keys which don't receive any requests/activity for more than 60 seconds.  Thus, the slowest rate which can be enforce is one request per minute, or 0.0166 requests per second.